# Should sprocs(always) return complete entity?

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I'm in the process of adding EF (4.2) to an existing .NET project.

The existing code base mainly relied on ADO.NET to call multiple sprocs.  Now that we are moving towards EF, I want to make sure we do so in the best, most maintainable way.

My issue is that the current sproc code base does not always return complete information for the entities they are named after:

GetUsersByAdministrator(int adminId)

The existing (sproc)code only returns a userId and first and last names.

To me this function does not return "Users", and should not be included (as named) in the Users business logic.

To me it seems troublesome if we give the impression that a function returns a "User" but does not return the complete entity.

**TL;DR**

When implementing a BLL should all backing stored procedures materialize a complete entity?

e.g. Should a static method on a Users class, called GetUsersByXYZ always be required to return a complete User object?

User.GetUsersByXYZ(int id)

Should these functions be better located in a separate assembly of utility functions and the methods be renamed to more appropriate names Util.GetUserIdAndNamesByXYZ?

Answer (score 1):

> When implementing a BLL should all backing stored procedures materialize a complete entity?

No. They can materialize entity, complex type or even unmapped class.

> Should a static method on a Users class, called GetUsersByXYZ always be required to return a complete User object?

That is about naming. What your stored procedures currently returns is projection of user data - it returns only data necessary in some context. So lets give the projection another type name like `UserNameInfo` and use it.

> Should these functions be better located in a separate assembly of
>   utility functions and the methods be renamed to more appropriate names
>   Util.GetUserIdAndNamesByXYZ?

Helper assemlby or not it will still be dependent on EF => it is part of data access.